# How to write conditional dependency base on build type in gradle

Tags: gradle

There is dependency in my sub project

```
dependencies {
    ...
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    ...
}
```

I don't know how to disable this dependency under particular build type.

Maybe I can define different project property, then use them in if-else statement. but... how to define properties according to build type?